# Given a vector x, can we say something about an A such that A x = x?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Let us assume that a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is given and we are looking for a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ which yields $A x = x$. That is, we perform a sort of reverse questioning: Instead of having a given $A$ and an unknown $x$, the vector $x$ is known but $A$ not.

Is there any theory which discusses such sort of equations? Pardon me if I am missing something completely trivial, but it would be great if someone could give me a hint.

Best wishes,
Andreas

Comment: Do you know about eigenvalues?

Comment: We can assume that A has the eigenvalue one and that this is the largest of all eigenvalues.

Comment: It's the same problem to find a matrix such that $A^2=A$

Comment: I am not sure what you are after. The set of matrices $A$ with $Ax=0$ forms a vector subspace of the space of all matrices. For your case, not sure what can be said.

Comment: @user98239: I fail to understand why $1$ should be the largest eigenvalue.

Comment: @lhf Ah, so silly! I was thinking of $Ax=0$. OK: The set of matrices of the form $A-I$ where $Ax=x$ forms a subspace. So the space of $A$s is an affine space. Perhaps the question is after characterizations of the space in terms of dimension, etc?

Comment: At least $A=I$ is a trivial solution. I don't know how much would help this observation, but no one pointed out that until now.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is that you try to solve Ax=x that has $n^2$ unknown variable with n equation then you can give arbitrary value to $n^2-n$ extra variable then you solve your system

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to $(A-I)x = 0$, in other words, the rows of $A-I$ are orthogonal to the vector $x$.  Since each row of $A-I$ can be chosen independently, this makes the question a bit uninteresting, which is why there isn't much theory written about it (everything can be understood from the individual rows, and nothing new can be understood by looking at the matrix as a whole).

Answer (score 1):

Each $A$ that has $x$ as it's eigenvector corresponding to an eigenvalue =1 is your answer.